# Creating a new user on firebase via the app but screen is not redirecting to homepage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a basic signup screen on flutter. I create a user succesfully but it still stays on the signup screen. But when i check on firebase, the user is there. I navigate to login page but i cant login with the newly created user.

If i make hot restart, now i can login with the newly created user.
I am confused. What is the case.

```
class AuthRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // user is logged in

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return HomeRoute();
            }

            // user is not logged in

            else {
              return const LoginRoute();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I have three screens. Auth page is checking if user is logged in or not. The other 2 is login page and register page.

Here is my register page;

```
class RegisterRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterRoute> createState() => _RegisterRouteState();
}

class _RegisterRouteState extends State<RegisterRoute> {
// controllers for text fields
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

// register user method
  void registerUser() async {
    // loading logo

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try {
      if (passwordController.text == confirmPasswordController.text) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text,
        );

        // pop the loading circle
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        // show error message, passwords do not match

        wrongEmail();
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      // pop the loading circle

      Navigator.pop(context);
      // wrong email

      if (error.code == "invalid-email") {
        wrongEmail();
      }

      // wrong password

      else if (error.code == "invalid-credential") {
        wrongPassword();
      }
    }
  }

  // wrong email message

  void wrongEmail() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Yanlış e-posta"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // wrong password message

  void wrongPassword() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Yanlış parola"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is my HomeRoute;

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeRoute({super.key});

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  // log out user

  void logoutUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text("Home Route"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: logoutUser,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("${user.email!} olarak giriş yapıldı"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, signing up the authStateChanges() stream doesn't emit the updated state. You can try the following approach to update the state:

```
if (passwordController.text == confirmPasswordController.text) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text,
        );

        Navigator.pop(context);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()),
        );
      } else {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        wrongPassword();
      }
```

Comment: My friend thank you very much. Now it is directing properly but now when i try to logout from home screen using the logout button on appbar, it is not working. Why is that? This is the button i am referring to:  https://ibb.co/yVPWMV9

Comment: add the code to your post

Comment: Okay I added the of my home page as well now.

Comment: change return type to Future<void> as it is an async process : Future<void> logoutUser() async => await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

Comment: I did like this but still the same;

// log out user

  Future<void> logoutUser() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }